# HTML how to get video when link is pasted

Tags: javascript, html

In some websites(for example Quora) when you paste link in `textarea` it automatically get the video or image from that link. How can I build the same thing? What language or library should I use?

Comment: use javascript to set the `src` attribute of a video tag, if you want for example to load youtube-links / vimeo links, you have to check they embed methods and individual treat the links

Comment: well since it's a webpage you pretty much have no choice but to use JavaScript (or something that compiles to JavaScript). As for frameworks, asking for recommendations is off-topic, but you don't really need a framework as such. Break it down into the steps required: Use an event handler to monitor when the value of the textarea changes. 2) Read the value from the textarea. 3) check it looks like a plausible URL 4) set the "src" of a video control to point to that URL. Have you tried to do anything so far? Once you break it down like that it's a set of quite simple steps.